# Decision Tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog

The following is my Prolog program for a decision tree which gives output oil or telecommunication or computers (investment option for the person:oil-high risk,telecommunication- moderate risk,computer-stable risk) depending on the input given name,marital_status, income and mortgage. But I am getting an error! 
    moderate_risk(X):-ask_marital_status(X,Y), Y=married, ask_income(X,I), 
                I=<50000, ask_mortgage(X,Z), Z=<50000,!.

```
moderate_risk(X):-ask_marital_status(X,M),M=married,ask_income(X,I), I>50000,!.


moderate_risk(X):-ask_marital_status(X,M), M=single, ask_income(X,I), I=<35000,!.


stable_risk(X):-ask_marital_status(X,M), M=married, ask_income(X,I), I=<50000,


                ask_mortgage(X,Z), Z>50000,!.


stable_risk(X):-ask_marital_status(X,M), M=single, ask_income(X,I), I>35000,  


                        ask_age(X,A),A>50,!.


high_risk(X):-ask_marital_status(X,M), M=single, ask_income(X,I), I>35000,



                     ask_age(X,A),A=<50,!.


invest(X,oil):-stable_risk(X),!.


invest(X,telecommunications):-moderate_risk(X),!.


invest(X,computers):-high_risk(X),!.

main(X,Z):-var(X), write('what is your name?'),read(X), invest(X,Z),!.


main(X,Z):-invest(X,Z),!.


ask_marital_status(X,Y):-marital_status(X,Y).


ask_marital_status(X,Y):-not(marital_status(X,Y)), write('what is your marital



  status:married or single?'), read(Y), asserta(marital_status(X,Y)).


    ask_income(X,Y):-income(X,Y).


ask_income(X,Y):-not(income(X,Y)),write('what is your annual income?'), read(Y),


asserta(income(X,Y)).


ask_mortgage(X,Z):-mortgage(X,Z).


ask_mortgage(X,Z):-not(mortgage(X,Z)),write('what is your remaining mortgage?'),


 read(Z), asserta(mortgage(X,Z)).


ask_age(X,A):-not(age(X,A)).


ask_age(X,A):-not(age(X,A)), write('what is your age?'), read(A), asserta(age(X,A)).
```

Comment: Your `ask_age/2` is wrong: the first clause should read `ask_age(X, A) :- age(X, A).`. Instead, you have written `not(age(X, A))`.

Comment: Please put some effort to format your code!

Answer (score 1):

As SWI-Prolog is telling you, `marital_status/2` is not defined. You reference it in:

```
ask_marital_status(X,Y) :- marital_status(X,Y).
```

But you never defined it anywhere.

Comment: It is a rule,not a function.Isn't it supposed to take the value X from ask_marital_status(X,Y) and continue

Comment: @user2056600 You need to define it as a dynamic predicate.

Comment: @user2056600 still, you need to define it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get when I try to compile:

```
Warning: The predicates below are not defined. If these are defined
Warning: at runtime using assert/1, use :- dynamic Name/Arity.
Warning: 
Warning: age/2, which is referenced by
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:80:16: 1-st clause of ask_age/2
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:81:19: 2-nd clause of ask_age/2
Warning: income/2, which is referenced by
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:70:19: 1-st clause of ask_income/2
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:71:22: 2-nd clause of ask_income/2
Warning: marital_status/2, which is referenced by
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:64:4: 1-st clause of ask_marital_status/2
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:66:8: 2-nd clause of ask_marital_status/2
Warning: mortgage/2, which is referenced by
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:75:21: 1-st clause of ask_mortgage/2
Warning:    /home/bvassile/Documents/code/prolog/marital.pl:76:24: 2-nd clause of ask_mortgage/2
true.
```

So, I follow the recommendation in the first two lines of the warning message an add the following to the top of the file:

```
:- dynamic age/2, income/2, marital_status/2, mortgage/2.
```

I also corrected the mistake in the definition of `ask_age/2`. With this program (with corrected formatting):

```
:- dynamic age/2, income/2, marital_status/2, mortgage/2.

moderate_risk(X) :-
    ask_marital_status(X,Y),
    Y=married,
    ask_income(X,I), I=<50000,
    ask_mortgage(X,Z), Z=<50000,
    !.

moderate_risk(X) :-
    ask_marital_status(X,M),
    M=married,
    ask_income(X,I), I>50000,
    !.

moderate_risk(X) :-
    ask_marital_status(X,M),
    M=single,
    ask_income(X,I), I=<35000,
    !.

stable_risk(X) :-
    ask_marital_status(X,M),
    M=married,
    ask_income(X,I), I=<50000,
    ask_mortgage(X,Z), Z>50000,
    !.

stable_risk(X) :-
    ask_marital_status(X,M),
    M=single,
    ask_income(X,I), I>35000,
    ask_age(X,A), A>50,
    !.

high_risk(X) :-
    ask_marital_status(X,M),
    M=single,
    ask_income(X,I), I>35000,
    ask_age(X,A),A=<50,
    !.

invest(X,oil) :-
    stable_risk(X),
    !.

invest(X,telecommunications) :-
    moderate_risk(X),
    !.

invest(X,computers) :-
    high_risk(X),
    !.

main(X,Z) :-
    var(X),
    write('what is your name?'), read(X),
    invest(X,Z),
    !.
main(X,Z) :-
    invest(X,Z),
    !.

ask_marital_status(X,Y) :-
    marital_status(X,Y).
ask_marital_status(X,Y) :-
    not(marital_status(X,Y)),
    write('what is your marital status:married or single?'), read(Y),
    asserta(marital_status(X,Y)).

ask_income(X,Y) :- income(X,Y).
ask_income(X,Y) :- \+ income(X,Y),
    write('what is your annual income?'), read(Y),
    asserta(income(X,Y)).

ask_mortgage(X,Z) :- mortgage(X,Z).
ask_mortgage(X,Z) :- \+ mortgage(X,Z),
    write('what is your remaining mortgage?'), read(Z),
    asserta(mortgage(X,Z)).

ask_age(X,A) :- age(X,A).
ask_age(X,A) :- \+ age(X,A),
    write('what is your age?'), read(A),
    asserta(age(X,A)).
```

You will notice that you have a silly amount of cuts. Most of them are probably unnecessary. Especially cuts at the end of clause bodies are always never meant to be there. You can try and remove all cuts at ends of clauses and see if this changes the behaviour of your program.
I can now load and run the code with `?- main(boris, Z).`.

Comment: Is there a way to restriction domain for Married to single or married and if a user enters not available when asked for input with question what is your marital status:married or single.If he gives a illegal input such as No then it should ask the same question what is your marital status:married or single..

Comment: @Boris upvoted, this is a way more comprehensive answer than mine.